# How to determine Big-o complexity if it only depends on values of input rather than input size?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I just saw javascript code about sorting which uses `setTimeout` as shown

```
var list = [2,  5, 10, 4, 8, 32]; 
var result = [];
list.forEach( n => setTimeout(() => result.push(n), n));
```

It is interesting because in js `setTimeout` is asynchronous so if you wait for sufficient time, `result` will be sorted array. It is deterministic depends on only values of data but not the size of the input so I have no idea how to determine Big-O (time complexity) of this approach.

Comment: It doesn't really work at all. After running this code, `result` is `undefined`.

Comment: If you want to determine complexity of the whole algorithm, evaluating code until all values have been pushed into `result`, you will need to take into account the implementation of `setTimeout` and, by extension, the whole event loop. If you cannot do that, you will need to define your own "browser environment" *machine model*.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one statement; This is work.
`list = [2,  5, 10, 4, 8, 32];  result = []; list.forEach( n => setTimeout(() => result.push(n), n));`

I wonder that what if I consider that `setTimeout` is asynchronous, then I don't need to take into account its implementation because running time will only depend on the max(values)

Comment: Running time depends on both max(values) and len(values) -- take the example of having a max(values) of `1` and len(values) of `999999999999`. And vice versa: a max(values) of `9999999999` with len(values) of `1`. Both scenarios increase the running time of the algorithm, which suggests that the complexity of the function is dependent on **two** variables.

Comment: @Imtk Wow!! Thats pretty great approach of sorting!!

Comment: @PranshuKhandal No, it's not.

Comment: @Bergi Not in sense of efficiency, but the way it works is a new and nice for me!! Probably needs to be learnt, that was what i was saying.. :)

Comment: @PranshuKhandal I guess it's working like an external heapsort. It should be fine regarding efficiency, but it's very impractical because of its asynchrony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR;** it depends on how you define the complexity of `setTimeout()`

---

When discussing algorithmic complexity, we have to answer the following questions:

- What are my inputs?
- What is a unit of work in the hypothetical machine that my algorithm runs in?

In some cases, how we define our inputs is dependent on what the algorithm is doing and how we defined our unit of work. The problem is complicated when using built-in functions as we have to define the complexity of those functions so we can take them into account and calculate the overall complexity of the algorithm.

What is the complexity of `setTimeout()`? That's up for interpretation. I find it helpful to give `setTimeout()` a complexity of `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of milliseconds passed to the function. In this case I've decided that each millisecond that is counted internally by `setTimeout()` represents one unit of work.

Given that `setTimeout()` has complexity `O(n)`, we must now determine how it fits into the rest of our algorithm. Because we are looping through `list` and calling `setTimeout()` for each member of the list, we multiply `n` with another variable, let's call it `k` to represent the size of the list.

Putting it all together, the algorithm has complexity **`O(k * n)`**, where `k` is the length of the numbers given, and `n` is the maximum value in the list.

Does this complexity make sense? Let's do a sanity check by interpreting the results of our analysis:

- Our algorithm takes longer as we give it more numbers ✓
- Our algorithm takes longer as we give it larger numbers ✓

Notice that the key to this conclusion was determining the complexity of `setTimeout()`. Had we given it a constant `O(1)` complexity, our end result would have been `O(k)`, which IMO is misleading.

---

**Edit:**

Perhaps a more correct interpretation of `setTimeout()`'s contribution to our complexity is `O(n)` for all inputs, where `n` is the maximum value of a given list, regardless of how many times it is called.

In the original post, I made the assumption that `setTimeout()` would run `n` times for each item in the list, but this logic is slightly flawed as `setTimeout()` conceptually "caches" previous values, so if it is called with `setTimeout(30), setTimeout(50), and setTimeout(100)`, it will run 100 units of work (as opposed to 180 units of work, which was the case in the original post).

Given this new "cached" interpretation of `setTimeout()`, the complexity is **O(k + n)**, where `k` is the length of the list, and `n` is the maximum value in the list.

**Fun fact:**
This happens to have the same complexity as [Counting Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/), whose complexity is also a function of list size and max list value

Comment: But what if I consider that each setTimeout() is asynchronous so the complexity should be O(k), isn’t it?

Comment: I made an edit to my post which models `setTimeout()`'s complexity more accurately than the original post, with the new complexity being **O(k + n)**. The only case where the algorithm would have **O(k)** complexity is when we give `setTimeout()` a complexity of **O(1)** (constant), which I think is incorrect as our function runs slower when we give a larger and larger maximum value, suggesting that we need to take maximum value into account in complexity analysis.

Comment: @Christian Santos but what about .forEach() it needs time to compute on large arrays, should it not be counted??

Comment: @PranshuKhandal the forEach should always be counted, it is the `k` in **O(n + k)**, where `k` is the length of the list and `n` is the maximum value of the list

Comment: @Cristian Santos thnx got that :)